# tFPDF unicode characters in Arial bold

Tags: unicode, utf-8, fpdf, bold

I'm trying to create PDF by FPDF (tFPDF) but I still can't create output with correct charset.

Problem is in czech letters: ě,š,č,ř,ž,ů etc...

Source:

```
<?php
require_once('../tfpdf/tfpdf.php');

define("_SYSTEM_TTFONTS", "C:/Windows/Fonts/");

$pdf = new tFPDF('P','mm','A5');

$pdf->SetMargins(8,5,8);
$pdf->AddPage();

// Pracoviště
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$pdf->Cell(25,12,'Pracoviště:','L',0);

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I need to write "Pracoviště:" but output is "PracoviÅ¡tÄ›:".

For regular Arial I solved it by:

```
$pdf->AddFont('Arial','','arial.ttf',true);
```

but it doesen't work for bold.

I tried:

```
$pdf->AddFont('Arial','','arial.ttf',true); // Arial
$pdf->AddFont('Arial','B','arialbd.ttf',true); // Arial Bold

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$pdf->Cell(25,12,'Pracoviště:'); // output: Pracoviště:
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$pdf->Cell(25,12,'Pracoviště:'); // output: PracoviÅ¡tÄ›:
```

Interestingly if I use Arial Black file, it works, but it's not font what I need.

```
$pdf->AddFont('Arial','','arial.ttf',true); // Arial
$pdf->AddFont('Arial','B','ariblk.ttf',true); // Arial Black

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$pdf->Cell(25,12,'Pracoviště:'); // output: Pracoviště:
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$pdf->Cell(25,12,'Pracoviště:'); // output: Pracoviště: - but Arial Black font, I need Arial Bold
```

Why Arial works, Arial Black works too and Arial Bold doesn't work? How to solve it?